# How to create an equivalent of a background thread for an auto-scaling instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Been reading up a bit on background threads and it seems to only be allowed for backend instance. I have created an LRU instance cache that I want to call period cleanup jobs on to remove all expired objects. This will be used in both frontend and backend instances.

I thought about using deferred or taskqueue but those do not have the option to route a request back to the same instance. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job that will start a task. In this task, you can call all your instances to clean up expired objects.

Comment: How do you have a task call on all instances to do something? Looking at the docs I don't see where I can specify that.

Comment: You can address each instance directly, and call any handler that you like, e.g. "/delete_expired_objects".

Comment: I read about how to address each instance directly but the docs seem to mention that if you're using auto scaling, then instance are anonymous.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine
Either way, even the module api doesn't seem to have any functions where I can programmatically retrieve all instance ids.

Answer (score 0):

Let [memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache) do the work for you.  You can either let data expire based on [LRU cache behavior](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_How_cached_data_expires) or give data an expiration time.

Comment: That's certainly a choice but I was thinking more of a cache that lives in the instance's memory.

Comment: @user5831382:  Can't you simply use a limit? For example, store up to 1,000 objects. If you bump into this limit, delete all that expired or 200 oldest?

Comment: I am currently doing that -- doing a cleanup when the cache is full. However, sometimes if the cache ends up filling up quick it will end up kicking off the cleanup process more often than I'd like.

Comment: So the cleanup task is based on when the cache is full?  Why not use a circular buffer that automatically deletes the oldest object when a new one is added?  Or something similar.